# Are there non-constant functions $a(z)$, $b(z)$, $c(z)$, $d(z)$ satisfying $a(z) \cos (z) + b(z) \sin (z)=c(z) \cos (z) + d(z) \sin (z)$?

Tags: trigonometry

I'm kind of puzzled by the equality
$$a(z) \cos (z) + b(z) \sin (z)=c(z) \cos (z) + d(z) \sin (z)$$
If $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ are constant, then $a=c$ and $b=d$,
but is there a more general form of functions $a(z)$, ..., $d(z)$ that will satisfy this?

By the way, is there a name for these coefficient-functions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For those $z$'s that one of $\cos z$ or $\sin z$ is zero, you can say something about $a(z), b(z), c(z), d(z)$.

Comment: Certainly, any functions (constant or not) with $a(z)\equiv c(z)$ and $b(z)\equiv d(z)$ work, but you probably intended to exclude this trivial solution. Here's something to consider: Write $$a(z)\cos z+b(z)\sin z=c(z)\cos z+d(z)\sin z=p(z)$$ Solve for $\cos z$ and $\sin z$, and substitute into $\cos^2z+\sin^2z=1$. This yields a relation we can express (suppressing "$z$"s) as $$p^2\left(\;(a-c)^2+(b-d)^2\;\right)=(a d-b c)^2$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a vector $\bf u$ and a vector $\bf n$ normal to it.

The two vectors $\bf v = \alpha \bf u + \beta \bf n$ and  $\bf w = \alpha \bf u + \gamma \bf n$
have the same dot product with $\bf u$.

[image: vett_rot_1]

Taking therefore the rotating vector $\bf u(z) =(\cos z , \sin z)$
and  $\bf n =(- \sin z, \cos z)$ normal to it, the two vectors
$$
\eqalign{
  & {\bf v} = \alpha (z){\bf u} + \beta (z){\bf n} = \left( {\alpha (z)\cos z - \beta (z)\sin z,\;\alpha (z)\sin z + \beta (z)\cos z} \right)  \cr 
  & {\bf w} = \alpha (z){\bf u} + \gamma (z){\bf n} = \left( {\alpha (z)\cos z - \gamma (z)\sin z,\;\alpha (z)\sin z + \gamma (z)\cos z} \right) \cr} 
$$
have the same dot product with $\bf u(z)$, i.e. their components, depending on any three functions $\alpha (z), \beta (z) \gamma (z)$,
are the four coefficients $a(z),b(z),c(z),d(z)$ that you requested.